# Why don't I get notifications from messaging apps on my phone?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, operating-system, instant-messaging

If I don't have the app open, I don't get messages that people send to me. When I open the app, I see unread messages. I have seen this with LinkedIn messages, Quora messages, and Signal recently (these are the apps I do use - I don't know if there are more apps that are showing this behavior). And this has been going on for about a year now, if not a little more; it didn't use to be like this before. The only apps where I do get notifications for messages are Facebook Messenger, Instagram messages and WhatsApp (basically, all Facebook owned apps), in addition to the plain old SMS.

I have checked in App settings; I have turned on notifications, so I should receive notifications for messages. But I don't. For example, see this screenshot of LinkedIn permissions, where you can clearly see that that I have enabled every kind of notification there is, but I still don't get notifications for messages that are sent to me:

[image]

And here's a screenshot of the battery optimization settings of LinkedIn, where you can see that I have not enabled battery optimization for it, and given it permission to run in the background:

[image]

If I further click on "Battery optimization", this is what I get:

[image]

Could someone please explain in detail, is this the result of some OS update, possibly as part of an attempt to extend battery life? How do I make it such that I get notifications for all messages sent to me all the time, regardless of whether I have the app open or not? I don't care much about other notifications (likes, shares, etc), but it is important to me that I get notifications for DMs (direct messages) sent to me.

Comment: Hello. Have you made sure that your app is exempted from Battery optimization settings? You should be able to see this in Settings -> Apps -> your app -> Battery optimization.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of it in the question now. It says "app can use battery in background", so I assume it has been exempted?

Comment: No. Under Battery optimization, choose "Don't optimize" or something similar.

Comment: @Firelord I've added a screenshot of what I can see when I go to "battery optimization". Please have a look.

Comment: Make/model and OS version of your device would be helpful. Related: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: May be the push notification got defect by an update. I would clear the app data and re-initialize the app. That will get you a new push notification token and thus also reset the push functionality. If it still not work afterwards then it is a device problem.

Comment: @Robert How do I do that? Actually, about it being a device problem, my wife has an iPhone 11 and she has been facing similar issues too. So, I wouldn't be so quick to call it a device problem. Do you get messages from messaging apps without fail?

Comment: Android settings -> apps -> LinkedIn -> Clear app data. Or just uninstall the app and later reinstall it. Android and iPhone don't have anything in common even the used push notification system is different. Thus observations made on an iPhone may or may not indicate a general problem.

Comment: Ok, cleared the app data. Let's see if this fixes it. And yeah, I know nothing's common between iOS and Android, but I was just replying to the "device problem" comment, that if there's an iPhone displaying similar issues as well, it can't simply be that both devices have now suddenly become faulty. Actually, things shouldn't even be this convoluted - not every layman will post a question or google about it and figure out what to do - notifications for messages should come on our phones at all times, simple as that.